# akamai redirects to origin server 302 redirects

Tags: akamai

I have a jsp (`test1.jsp`) which has a code `response.sendRedirect("xxx/jsp/test2.jsp");`

when i access it with akamai url, it is redirecting to origin server.

```
http://akamai.domain/xxx/jsp/test1.jsp
```

redirects to

```
http://origin.domain/xxx/jsp/test2.jsp
```

can some one advise what has to be done to fix it?

Comment: What application server is this running under? Is origin.domain set as the default redirection target within your server?

Comment: we are using jboss eap 4.3 as app server and apache as webserver. can you advise what to do to set it as default redirection target? I have these settings  in httpd.conf <VirtualHost ipadress:80>

ServerName vhost.domain:80
ServerAlias akamai.domain
ServerAlias origin.domain
ProxyPass /contextpath balancer://cluster lbmethod=byrequests stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid timeout=60
ProxyPassReverse /contextpath http://jbossip:port/contextpath
ProxyPreserveHost On

</VirtualHost>

Answer (score 1):

Prepend the Akamai CDN URL to the path:

```
String akamai_url = "http://akamai.domain/xxx/jsp/test2.jsp";

response.sendRedirect(akamai_url);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.However issue is with the akamai configurations.We have done some changes and it got fixed.